# How to set title on UIButton

Tags: iphone

How to set text on `UIButton`

```
topYellowButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
topYellowButton2.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 90, 20);

[topYellowButton2 setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.6 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
topYellowButton2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
topYellowButton2.frame=CGRectMake(80, 0, 90, 20);
[topYellowButton2 setTitle:@"Your Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Title for both Normal and Highlighted

```
[topYellowButton2 setTitle:@"Button Title" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
[topYellowButton2 setTitle:@"Button Title" forControlState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[topYellowButton2 setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line:

```
[topYellowButton2 setTitle:@"my button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```